# Recursive Longest Common Subsequence looping or taking forever?

Tags: javascript, java, recursion

I am developing a JavaScript application and I needed a recursive algorithm for the longest common subsequence, so I went [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#JavaScript) and tried this one out.
It goes like this:

```
function lcs(a, b) {
  var aSub = a.substr(0, a.length - 1);
  var bSub = b.substr(0, b.length - 1);

  if (a.length === 0 || b.length === 0) {
    return '';
  } else if (a.charAt(a.length - 1) === b.charAt(b.length - 1)) {
    return lcs(aSub, bSub) + a.charAt(a.length - 1);
  } else {
    var x = lcs(a, bSub);
    var y = lcs(aSub, b);
    return (x.length > y.length) ? x : y;
  }
}
```

It worked fine with the few test cases i tried until now, but I found that it loops on the following test case:

a: This entity works ok

b: This didn't work ok but should after

It also loops with:

a: This entity works ok

b: This didn't work as well

which at some point should get in the middle branch.

I have noticed that it is a translation of a Java version ([here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Java)) of the same algorithm. It goes like this:

```
public static String lcs(String a, String b){
    int aLen = a.length();
    int bLen = b.length();
    if(aLen == 0 || bLen == 0){
        return "";
    }else if(a.charAt(aLen-1) == b.charAt(bLen-1)){
        return lcs(a.substring(0,aLen-1),b.substring(0,bLen-1))
            + a.charAt(aLen-1);
    }else{
        String x = lcs(a, b.substring(0,bLen-1));
        String y = lcs(a.substring(0,aLen-1), b);
        return (x.length() > y.length()) ? x : y;
    }
}
```

I supposed that the JavaScript translation was wrong assuming that String.substr() and String.substring() were the same (which they aren't). 
To be sure that it wasn't the case, I tried the Java one on the same test case [here](http://ideone.com/sWZ55b).

Guess what? Also the java version does not end.

I am struggling to debug it, as it is recursive.
Anyone has any idea on what is going wrong with it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "It worked fine until now, where I found that it loops on the following test case:

a: This entity works ok

b: This didn't work ok but should after" . Can you clarify?

Comment: Are you sure that you do understand how **long** this solution may work for even small inputs? If on every iteration the algorithm enters the last case, then its time complexity is O(2^n), where `n` is the length of your shortest string.

Comment: LCS is an NP-hard problem and needs heuristics to become tractable. Your code is the naïve, brute-force algorithm.

Comment: I know that it is hard. It is not a crucial part of my tool, that is why i don't care for the runtime at the moment. I just needed something that would give me an output. That is not part of the problem here, the problem to me seems the correctness of this exponential recursive algorithm.

@Diego Martinoia: Sure. Please let me know if I can provide more details. I just tried it on a few test cases and it worked, but on this it fails.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, LCS for 2 input sequences is not an NP-hard problem, it has a straightforward dynamics programming solution that works in O(N^2) time.

Comment: @user3707125 Also in O(N^2) space.

Comment: @funforums "NP-hard" isn't a colloquial term, it means that you cannot get "something that would give you an output" in a reasonable amount of time. But, as user3707125 pointed out, I mistook the complexity of the more general n-input LCS for your special case of 2-input LCS, which is actually a P problem. However, the algorighm you actually implemented *is* NP.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia a: `This entity works ok` and  b: `This didn't work ok but should after` are the two strings which are the input to the function.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: I know what it means, I am a computer science graduate. I said it is hard in runtime because I have no proof at the moment to confirm that it is NP-hard. The algorithm is undoubtly exponential possibly in runtime so yes, but as I said that's fine for me at the moment.

Comment: So your claim is that your input is simply small enough to work even with an exponential algorithm? It's longer than 50 chars.

Comment: And what are these two a and b strings? I mean, what is their content?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia The string _a_ contains `This entity works ok`.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: You may be right. It is possible that I got fooled by the output I was getting while profiling. That brought me to think it was trying the same substrings all over again. 
It can be possibly going over the same strings all over again but across different branches of recursion, but not strictly looping forever. I will run more detailed tests. Thanks.

What I can say is that at the moment I am running a java test with smaller strings and it also takes forever. See question for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, the program itself is correct. The issue you are experiencing is due that, in this implementation, the code has an exponential time complexity, and therefore takes A LONG time to run with your example input. If you let it run for a LONG time, it will return the correct result.

As others have also pointed out in the comments, LCS between two Strings is solvable with a lower time complexity using dynamic programming, which will solve it much quicker. Refer to the internet for more help ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) ) or, better, try to solve it yourself thinking about the fact that there are, for each String of length n, exactly N^2 substrings. You can trivially solve it in N^2*M^2 (n m are the lengths of the two strings) by just checking if any substring of a is present in b. Ask yourself if you can do better for exercise? If yes how, if no, why.

Comment: I am afraid you are right and I was being naive. Should have thought this through more. That length is already very much for it to be solved in a useful time. Thanks for help!